# How do you start a Modded (Spigot) Minecraft server locally?

Tags: java, server, minecraft

I'm new to Java, so I followed [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/IU7qlx2PbDY) to learn how to make a Modded Minecraft server. But, in the tutorial, it isn't shown how to run the `.jar` file as a server, on my own PC. When I try the CMD command `java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar jarfile.jar`, I get this error:

```
no main manifest attribute, in jarfile.jar
```

Is there any way that I can run a server from the `.jar` file? Thank you in advance!

Comment: No one is going to watch the whole video to figure out what you did. Tell us what you did to produce that jarfile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the video is about is called a plugin, not a server or modification.
You create a `.jar` plugin that needs to be placed in the `plugins` folder in the server directory.

The plugin will be loaded during the server startup process, so it does not require a separate launch.

Comment: Oh I thought the jar file runs independently. Thanks!